# Bitbucket: Bind a file from tip to be download-able

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, bitbucket

I am working inside a private repository, and collaborate with my friend, who are not very friendly with SCM and stuff. All he need is to monitor the latest release from my development, which is 1 single executable file.

I was wondering instead of cloning the whole repo each time he want to get the latest changes (sometimes my changeset can consists of several large binary files that only being used upon development, not testing). Can I bind the executable file into the Download section in BitBucket?. So that everytime I build my project, the executable file will appear in the Download section and he can download it right away.

For now all I can see from Bitbucket's download section is just the manual upload and Tag/Snapshot download, which I presume will pack a certain changesets into a compressed file. Is there any chance I can do this?.

Thanks.

Comment: You *really* shouldn't have build-able binaries or executable programs checked into any source control system ever...

Comment: Build artifacts (usually the /bin/ output of a build) shouldn't be checked into the main repository no, but executables batch files etc. are fairly common

Comment: You can vote for this [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4550/allow-uploading-of-file-for-downloads-via) on Bitbucket. With this feature you could use the REST api in a git hook to automatically upload your binary into the downloads section.

Answer (score 3):

If your executable file is checked into the repository, you can link to it at a specific revision:

```
https://staging.bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>/raw/<revision>/file.exe
```

For example, this link will always give you the latest stable hg(1) man page from the Mercurial repository:

```
https://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/raw/stable/doc/hg.1.txt
```

This would give you latest README on the default branch from the Django repository:

```
https://bitbucket.org/django/django/raw/default/README
```

If your executable isn't checked into the repository (some prefer not to check in build artifacts), you'll need to manually upload them in the downloads section of your repository. There isn't a REST API for creating project downloads at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Would giving your friend an archive of the tip work? Try this URL:

> `https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project>/get/tip.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

@Idan's suggestion might already work for you, but if the archive is too big, you could set up an extra repository for binaries which automatically gets updated, committed and pushed by your build process. Then your fellow developer could download a comparatively small *tip* archive as suggested by Idan.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Idan's answer:
To fetch the latest version from the 'default' branch:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project>/get/default.tar.gz
```

You can replace 'default' by any other branch name, tag name or changeset (if you know it).