# Link latest file on Bitbucket Git repository

Tags: git, hyperlink, bitbucket

I have a public Git repository on Bitbucket. I want to link the latest version of a Read-Me file. Here's the link to a revision/commit:

https://bitbucket.org/wordless/thofu-interpreter/raw/5bfc37864c5d/ThoFu%20Interpreter/ReadMe.txt

I tried to replace the revision number with **tip** and **default**, but it didn't work. **Is there any way to get a permanent link to my latest files?**

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482121/bitbucket-bind-a-file-from-tip-to-be-download-able

Comment: `tip` is for mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Two ideas:

Use `master` in the url (this seems to work):

```
https://bitbucket.org/wordless/thofu-interpreter/raw/master/ThoFu%20Interpreter/ReadMe.txt
```

Another idea is to create a wiki page for your project, then use the wiki's functionality to [link to the latest version of a file](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Macro+Reference+for+Creole+Markup#MacroReferenceforCreoleMarkup-File) with this syntax:

```
<<file path/to/file [revision] [linenumber]>>
```

Just omit the revision and line number parameters, they are optional.

Then, refer to the wiki page everywhere else you'd like link to the read me file.

Comment: This also works linking to /src/ on bitbucket rather than raw https://bitbucket.org/user/repository/src/branch/path/file

Comment: @sunil-d Any idea how to that for private repo? When I click on raw url of a image in my private repo, it redirects to bytebucket.org & append a token so that it can be viewed publicly...like `https://bytebucket.org/$username/$repo/raw/$sha/$filename.jpg?token=$sometoken`. But the token is different for each file. Is there any way I can get/generate this type of token through bitbucket api?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I'm not sure how that might work. A quick google search pointed to possibly using their API to get an OAuth token, but I doubt that is the same token used here (who knows). Sorry I couldn't help any further!

Comment: bitbucket.org/user/repo/`raw/master`/ReadMe.txt  stopped working  
bitbucket.org/user/repo/`src/default`/ReadMe.txt  works though

Comment: The Creole syntax : `<<file path/to/file [revision] [linenumber]>>` doesn't work for README files. The README files on Bitbucket only support markdown file.

Comment: From your very Atlassian link, your "wiki to code" syntax "Links to a given file within the same project as the wiki. You cannot link to files that reside in repositories in other projects. The link syntax does not work with tags."

Comment: @adam: `/master/` works for me, is your branch named "Default" instead of "master"?

Comment: official answer from atlassian: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/hyperlinking-to-source-code-in-bitbucket-824476709.html

Answer (score 37):

There is an easy workaround for this issue by updating your relative links to `src/[branch_name]/path/to/file`. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: This should be used by default across the primary navigation. It is a much more common use case in my opinion.

Comment: The problem with that being the default is that it can become a 404, or refer to something completely different to what you intended.

Comment: Works great for me thus far, but it's early. @Antoine Pietri, how can it become a 404?

Comment: If you delete the file.

Comment: This schema doesn't work. Maybe it used to but it's not working anymore.

Comment: I just tested again, @Shreyas, and it still works for me. So, for example, the following url resolves the correct page (from a popular public repo): https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/0.2.2-maint/piston/emitters.py

Answer (score 13):

The canonical way to add a link to a file in your repository using Markdown (the default for Readme files and Wiki pages) is by linking to the relative path of the file.

For example, if I had a structure like so:

```
<repo root>
|-- my-file.txt
|    
|-- my-dir 
|    |-- my-other-file
```

I'd be able to link to them as follows:

```
[my-file](my-file.txt)
[my-dir](my-dir)
[some-other-file](my-dir/some-other-file)
```

Bitbucket will then automatically link to the file at the current branch that you are viewing the file at. If you're viewing the Readme file in the overview that will mean the default branch (usually 'master').

Comment: Of all the above methods, this was the most succinct way of solving it.

Comment: And it can also be used in a markdown syntax way of adding the link at the bottom to keep the markdown clean

Answer (score 3):

I am using master like this for the last zip file of the code :

```
https://bitbucket.org/MIUSER/MIREPO/get/master.zip
```

Where MIUSER is my user and MIREPO is the name of my app.

Hope that this works :D.

Answer (score 3):

Here are working links:

#### RAW:

```
https://bitbucket.org/wordless/thofu-interpreter/raw/HEAD/TODO.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default
```

#### Source:

```
https://bitbucket.org/wordless/thofu-interpreter/src/HEAD/TODO.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default
```