# Bitbucket URL to the latest version

Tags: git, url, mercurial, bitbucket, head

It seems that the answer from [Link latest file on Bitbucket Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692124/link-latest-file-on-bitbucket-git-repository) is not working anymore.

I converted the working URL 
https://bitbucket.org/confluence/fluxbox-tools/raw/0e7033dab29b144a01f29763ab9fc7c4fc104a16/fbxdgmenu.py
to
https://bitbucket.org/confluence/fluxbox-tools/raw/master/fbxdgmenu.py
but get 404 instead.

https://bitbucket.org/confluence/fluxbox-tools/raw/HEAD/fbxdgmenu.py
is not working either.

Is this still possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Mercurial repository, not a Git repository. (Bitbucket supports both.)

Use `default` instead of `master`: https://bitbucket.org/confluence/fluxbox-tools/raw/default/fbxdgmenu.py

Comment: I realized what you actually mean after I made the comment, and deleted it right away. But apparently you saw it within that several seconds.