# Atlassian Bitbucket and Confluence

Tags: git, bitbucket, confluence

I use bitbucket for my repos and confluence as wiki system.

In my repositories, i have text and markdown files.
I would like to link to those files (tag) in confluence.
When i go to bitbucket, i just get the repository url. Is there a way i go into this repository al like

```
Https://url-to-repo:1234/hash-or-tag/myfile.txt
```

I am used to svn where the svn repository is folder based... since git is not, is there some way to achieve my goal?

Ps: the extra-plus-option would be to not only being able to link to this files but to embed them as rendered text or even markdown but first i need to be able to even link to them.

Comment: The first part of the question is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692124/link-latest-file-on-bitbucket-git-repository
The second part about embedding the text in a confluence page should be a separate question, perhaps on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use "raw" links to files provided by Bitbucket:

```
https://url-to-repo:1234/raw/branch-or-hash-or-tag/path-to-file.txt
```

Comment: hi andry. it kinda works. i set the default branch in my repo to "develop". when i now access the ttps://url-to-repo:1234/raw/master.file.txt (readme.md) it redirects to the readme in develop... do you have an idea how the link can be forces to access the selected branch?